# Populate vector using an array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm learning how to use vectors in C++ using [this post](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/c-plus-plus-vector) and they gave the example below on populating a vector using an array. The syntax is a bit confusing though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Array of string objects
    std::string arr[] = {
        "first",
        "sec",
        "third",
        "fourth"
    };

    // Vector with a string array
    std::vector < std::string > vecOfStr(arr,arr +sizeof(arr) / sizeof(std::string)); //This line is confusing
    for (std::string str: vecOfStr)
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

As far as my understanding goes, right after the variable name for the vector there comes the size of the vector. I would imagine that would have simply been `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(std::string)` but instead it's `arr,arr +sizeof(arr) / sizeof(std::string)`. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `std::vector < std::string > vecOfStr(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));`

Comment: You want to look at *overloading*. `std::vector`'s constructor is overloaded, which means that, depending on the number **and** types of arguments it received, the behaviour is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector` has multiple constructors which you can choose from.
One of the constructors indeed receives the vector's length.
In your example, a different constructor is being used. One which receives two iterators.

You pass the constructor two pointers of `std::string` which serve as iterators.

The addition and division operators are just pointers arithmetics.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `std::array`. Then you can populate the vector as

```
std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

Get out of the habit of using C-style arrays.

Also; if you *insist* on using C-style arrays, then, at least, use `std::size()` if you need the number of elements.

Comment: I'm just following the tutorial, I'm guessing C-style arrays are bad?

Comment: @S.Ramjit Usually, you want to avoid using c-style arrays in c++ code. If you still need to use it, use 'std::array' instead, like Jesper suggested.